# Best way to sum time in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I have a table called **transactions** with two relevant fields to my question, _start_timestamp_ and _end_timestamp_. I need to sum the amount of time passed between all transactions where _end_timestamp_ is not null. So, the result must be something like *Total Time of Transactions: 1 hour and 18 minutes*

I've tried using *Carbon*, but I don't know how to sum all the lines of the table using it.

```
foreach($timestampStarts as $timestampStart){  
    $time = new Carbon($timestampStart->start_timestamp);
    $shift_end_time =new Carbon($timestampStart->end_timestamp);
    dd($time->diffForHumans($shift_end_time));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the MySQL [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function to calculate the difference:

```
Transaction::whereNotNull('_end_timestamp_')
    ->sum(DB::raw('TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, _start_timestamp_, _end_timestamp_)'));
```

This will give you the total in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You need to retrieve the total difference in minutes. Add the total difference and retrieve the diff for humans. You can retrieve like below:

```
$diffForHumans = null;
$nowDate = Carbon::now();
$diffInMinutes = 0;

foreach($timestampStarts as $timestampStart){  

    if(!empty($timestampStart->end_timestamp)){ // if the end timestamp is not empty

        $time = new Carbon($timestampStart->start_timestamp);
        $shift_end_time =new Carbon($timestampStart->end_timestamp);

        //Adding difference in minutes
        $diffInMinutes+= $shift_end_time->diffInMinutes($time);
    }
}
$totalDiffForHumans = $now->addMinutes($diffInMinutes)->diffForHumans();
```